# Difference between CRON tab 0/5 and */5?

Tags: cron

Is there any difference between creating a CRON tab using `0/5` and `*/5`?
For example:

```
0/5 * * * *
```

vs

```
*/5 * * * *
```

Comment: [`crontab(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/crontab.5.html) says that steps (`/N`) are allowed with ranges and `*` is shorthand for the range `first-last` for that field. It doesn't say anything for steps without ranges, so I'd assume illegal syntax, or ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This IBM support article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/c0054381.html) explains how stepping works. In the case of */5, it would occur every 5 minutes (0, 5, 10, etc).  That is the same as 0-59/5.  In the case of 0/5, I just tested it and it will never run.

Comment: Nathan is correct but I think 0/5 used to work on some older OS or kernel.

Comment: I think you are right. http://serverfault.com/a/583121/290434 says it would work, but that was not the case when I tried.

Comment: It works on some old versions of ubuntu. I have learned to hate ubuntu :D ubuntu is cool as a fanboy project and has no place in any enterprise production environment! Just because it CAN be used, does not mean it should be! Ubuntu is a massive fail at supporting older ubuntu versions, and also fails hard at integrating new packages. Ubuntu is just not a mature company and the makers do not seem to understand the needs of a persistent enterprise. Ubuntu will remain the fotm for fanboys only.

Comment: Side note, 0/5 notation is supported on AWS Lambda. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html